Unwrap a link in slate.js when clicking on editor
Goal 
First of all, I want to enter a link component inside my editor.
After that, I want the user to be able to write a text after the link.
e.g. www.google.gr Hello world
My problem 
When the user enters the link to the editor and tries to input some text ("hello"), the "hello" appears like it is part of the link.
My partial solution
onKeyDown={(event) => {
      const { selection } = editor;
      if (selection && Range.isCollapsed(selection)) {
        const { nativeEvent } = event;
        if (isKeyHotkey("left", nativeEvent)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          Transforms.move(editor, { unit: "offset", reverse: true });
          return;
        }
        if (isKeyHotkey("right", nativeEvent)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          Transforms.move(editor, { unit: "offset" });
          return;
        }
      }
    }}

I copied this code from Slate official example
The above code, "escapes" the link component when the User presses the "Left" arrow on the keyboard.
I would like to escape the link component when the user clicks outside of the link.
Desired Flow

User enters a URL
User clicks into the editor, outside of the link element
User types some dummy text
Final Result should be: www.google.gr Hello world

